# Swift: NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData returns nil but the json seems ok

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to get a JSON, but `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` returns `nil`, but the JSON looks ok:

```
var url = "http://andreid.imcserver.ro/test/service.php"
var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!){
            (data, response, error) in
            var error: NSError?
            var data2 = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println(data)
            println(data2)

            var response: NSDictionary? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

            if let err = error {
                println("error parsing json")
                return
            }
```

Comment: Your code runs fine with me. any way to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: Can you provide the JSON please? EDIT: Nvm, url has it

Comment: How exactly do you know the result is nil? This is an asynchronous method, are you checking the result before the JSON is actually delivered?

Comment: So, somebody actually gave me this website https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to check my JSON(I see that he erased his comment) and it turns out my JSON is bad. I checked it with jsbeautifer.org and it found nothing, this website told my that the first word 'posts' was not in quotes, I introduced it in quotes and it worked. I even asked some colleagues(php and javascript programmers) if there is a problem with it and they said no, but somehow swift did not like it that way

Comment: You can find the JSON at the url

Comment: Object keys must **always** be wrapped in quotes in JSON. Omitting quotes is only valid for JavaScript, not JSON. See http://json.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, please see edited code below.

```
var url = "http://andreid.imcserver.ro/test/service.php"
        var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: nsURL!)
        var data: NSData
        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var error: NSErrorPointer?

        var jsonTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            println("\(data)")
            println("\(response)")
            println("\(error)")

            if error == nil
            {
                var jsonError: NSError?
                var jsonResponse: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &jsonError) as! NSDictionary

                println("\(jsonResponse)")

            }
            else
            {
                println("JSON PARse error")
            }
        })
        jsonTask.resume()
```

It works with me.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. With the code I used it did not liked that the word posts was not in quotes...strange thing

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). and its working fine.

here is the code for that:

```
var url = "http://andreid.imcserver.ro/test/service.php"
var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsURL!)
let json = JSON(data: data!)
println(json)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. With the code I used it did not liked that the word posts was not in quotes...strange thing